# Is there an Android ROM specifically designed for devices to be digital photo frames?

Tags: android-rom

Would anyone be aware of a specialized Android ROM crafted specifically for the purpose of turning the device into a digital photo frame? I have some pretty old Android devices that even when flashed with LineageOS and even trying out the the popular app [Fotoo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bo.fotoo&hl=en_US&gl=US) mentioned from [articles](https://www.slashgear.com/1226041/how-to-repurpose-your-old-tablet-into-a-digital-picture-frame/), it is still sluggish or tend to "freeze" up.